# Transforming 2d array to multipline object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im tring to transform an ugly array into a multiline cool Object but my brain is failing me.
Im trying to put this ugly thing

```
"location" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    -8.61901849508286, 
                    41.5311338460033
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61851692199707, 
                    41.5311338460033
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61851692199707, 
                    41.5312944769825
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61901849508286, 
                    41.5312944769825
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61901849508286, 
                    41.5311338460033
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
```

To this amazing thing:

```
const paths = [
      { lat: 41.53113384600326, lng: -8.619018495082855 },
      { lat: 41.53113384600326, lng: -8.61851692199707 },
      { lat: 41.53129447698251, lng: -8.61851692199707 },
      { lat: 41.53129447698251, lng: -8.619018495082855 },
      { lat: 41.53113384600326, lng: -8.619018495082855 }
    ];
```

I tried this

```
const polygon = this.props.places.places.map(place => {
      return place.location.coordinates.map(([lat, lng]) => ({ lat, lng }));
    });
```

And i tried flat()  but im failing and failing. Anyone has any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
place.location.coordinates.map(
    (values) => values.map(
        (data) => {lat: data[0], lng: data[1]}
    )
);
```

Comment: You’re welcome, think to validate the response to close that subject :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
//wrap the "ugly object" in curly brackets so it becomes a javascript object
var locationCoordinates =
{
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : 
        [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    -8.61901849508286, 
                    41.5311338460033
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61851692199707, 
                    41.5311338460033
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61851692199707, 
                    41.5312944769825
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61901849508286, 
                    41.5312944769825
                ], 
                [ 
                    -8.61901849508286, 
                    41.5311338460033
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
};
//get the coordinates portion of the object
var coordinates = locationCoordinates.location.coordinates[0];
var paths = [];//the amazing thing 
coordinates.forEach(function(value, index, array) 
{   //generate the required format and add it to the paths variable
    paths.push({lat: value[1], lng: value[0]});
});  
console.log(paths); //displays the required output
```

I hope this helps.